# gradle.properties in project build directory not read via Eclipse/Buildship - command line works fine

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I use the latest Eclipse (version 4.12) with Buildship Gradle Integration 3.0. 
I can see the tasks in the Gradle Tasks view, but I cannot run the tasks successfully.

When I run a task from the command line then it works fine.

When I run a task by double clicking the task in the Gradle Tasks view then the task fails with the following error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pfad[src] existiert nicht.

This translates to

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path[src] does not exist.

`src` is a directory defined in the project's gradle.properties file as follows:

```
GEN_ROOT_PATH=src
```

The project's gradle.properties file is in the same directory as the build.gradle script.
In the build.gradle file I refer to the property as `project.GEN_ROOT_PATH`

I believe that is what is what the exception complains about when I run the task from the Gradle Tasks view.

I do not understand, and I could not find helpful information in the internet to solve this issue.

As I said before, the tasks can be run successfully in the command line.
The tasks fail when run in Eclipse. Does anyone have an idea what the issue can be? How can I approach a possible solution?

Comment: Show us the actual `build.gradle` source. Does it work *without* using the `gradle.properties` values from inside Eclipse?

Comment: I cannot show it unfortunately, it is proprietary and I am afraid my company/client may not appreciate it. I mentioned that from the command line running the task works fine. I thought Gradle by default reads the `gradle.properties` file, independently of whether it was run by command line or an IDE. I guess the issue may be in the IDE.

Comment: That's one of the two questions.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. E.g. I perform two tests: 1. I double click the task in the Gradle Tasks view and see it fails with the above exception and 2. I run `gradle taskName` in the command line and it works fine. What tests would you suggest to help narrowing down on the issue ?